# SQL Syntax Error - Nested Queries

Tags: mysql

SQL isn't my strongest area and I am trying to query two tables pull back rows from both and count on of the rows at the same time. This is the code I have attempted.

```
SELECT author_name, tos_signed, date_signed
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_signed FROM Tos WHERE tos_signed = '1'
)
FROM Authors, Tos WHERE Authors.wordpress_id = Tos.wordpress_id;
```

Comment: You'll need to somehow relate the results of the sub select back to the results of the Tos in the outer query, otherwise you'll get the same number in all returned rows of the outer.

Comment: so what have you tried to fix it so far? what errors are you getting? what do you not understand? what is not working?

Comment: you should JOIN tables as well instead of comma separated from with a WHERE linking the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the syntax error you are missing comma after `date_signed` and for count the you can try this

```
SELECT author_name, tos_signed, date_signed,SUM(tos_signed = '1')  AS total_signed    
FROM Authors a
join  Tos t on 
a.wordpress_id = t.wordpress_id
GROUP BY your id col /* or the column you need to get the count for each group*/
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need this-

```
SELECT author_name, tos_signed, date_signed
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_signed FROM Tos a WHERE a.tos_signed = '1' and a.wordpress_id = Tos.wordpress_id
)
FROM Authors, Tos WHERE Authors.wordpress_id = Tos.wordpress_id;
```

Answer (score -1):

At this point every row would return the same entire count.
You want to have the *where* in your subselect.

```
SELECT author_name, 
       tos_signed, 
       date_signed,
       (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_signed  FROM Tos WHERE tos_signed = '1' 
                                                  and  Authors.wordpress_id = Tos.wordpress_id;
       )
    FROM Authors;
```

Comment: Authors is not defined in your sub-query and Tos is not defined in your outerquery

Comment: He knows authors from the orignal from, and he doesnt need data from tos as columns, only a result set.